# Django 1.5 GET 404 on static files

Tags: python, django, static, http-status-code-404

I need a little help with this, I've been searching for a solution with no results.

This are my settings:
settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT + '/static/'
)
```

Installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin', . . .
```

Running with DEBUG = TRUE:

```
August 01, 2013 - 16:59:44
Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6161
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/css/jquery-ui/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-    1.10.3.custom.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css     HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/js/messages.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/js/validate/jquery.validate.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/images/FERREMOLQUES2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
[01/Aug/2013 16:59:50] "GET /static/media/js/dynamic-style.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5904
```

As a special mention I'm running Django 1.5.1 and Python 2.7.5 in a **VIRTUALENV**.  I do not know if this configuration is causing the problem

Any help would be appreciate

Thanks.

**EDIT: When I off VIRTUALENV and install proper version of Django and the project's dependencies, My project works well, without any issue. . . statics are shown as it should**

Comment: You did remember to put things in your static folder, right?  It looks like it's expecting all of them to be in a single static folder instead of in each app.  Also, in Django 1.5 the docs recommend using `{% static <something> %}`

Comment: Of course, I take caution of that before post this problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hours and hours of searching for any solution, finally I found that this problem is a bug:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=962223

I'm not sure if this bug is by Django or Python, My Django version is 1.5.1 and Python is 2.7.5. I would need to proof in previous django and python version to see if bug is present.

My setting.py was in `DEBUG=False` when I change it to True the problem has gone, right now in development, I'm not worried about that, but I wait for a patch when my project reach production.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this helps me as well, but need to use false for the production server.  I am in django 1.10.5 and python 2.7.12, still encounter this issue.

Comment: Hi, later found this talked in django doc, and mentioned the setting for static file are different when DEBUG = True and False. Check the doc here.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure your `STATICFILE_DIRS` is correct? If your settings is like at the moment, the `static` folder is supposed to be in same level as `settings.py`.

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # it means settings.py is in PROJECT_ROOT?
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT + '/static/', # <= don't forget a comma here
)
```

My normal `settings.py` is a bit different:

```
ROOT_PATH = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '..')  # up one level from settings.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    path.abspath(path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static')), # static is on root level
)
```

Apart from that, you need `django.core.context_processors.static` as context processors:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # other context processors....
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
```

And enable the urlpattern in `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for fast response.In effect, settings.py is in the same level as static, in the root folder of the project there are the apps folders, the static folder, the settings and the manage.py. I add the comma but problem persist. . .

Comment: Thanks again, The only thing that could solve my problem even without change anything on the code was not using VIRTUALENV, but why? I do not understand why  I can no get static files working well with VIRTUALENV. . . And really need virtualenv,  I dont like to install every dependencies on my machine, and I like to proof things with python 3 and 2 same as django 1.4 and 1.5

Thanks anyway for help

Comment: For the record. I was having problems with my static files. I'm using django 1.4.3 and I was using STATIC_ROOT variable which was not compatible with STATICFILES_DIR. I just removed STATIC_ROOT and now it's working.

Comment: it is working for Django 1.6.5 but i didnot include TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in the settings.py and without that as well it is working like charm..

Comment: You sir are a genius

Answer (score 1):

This issue is happening because in NON DEBUG mode static files handler is WSGI as per below code lines, which does not handle settings.STATIC_ROOT path -

File Location - django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver

```
def get_handler(self, *args, **options):
    """
    Returns the static files serving handler wrapping the default handler,
    if static files should be served. Otherwise just returns the default
    handler.

    """
    handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
    use_static_handler = options.get('use_static_handler', True)
    insecure_serving = options.get('insecure_serving', False)
    if use_static_handler and (settings.DEBUG or insecure_serving):
        return StaticFilesHandler(handler)
    return handler
```

To fix this, I added one else check as shown in below code and it works fine.

```
  def get_handler(self, *args, **options):
        """
        Returns the static files serving handler wrapping the default handler,
        if static files should be served. Otherwise just returns the default
        handler.

        """
        handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
        use_static_handler = options.get('use_static_handler', True)
        insecure_serving = options.get('insecure_serving', False)
        if use_static_handler and (settings.DEBUG or insecure_serving):
            return StaticFilesHandler(handler)
        elif use_static_handler: 
            return StaticFilesHandler(handler)
        return handler
```

Thanks,
Gaurav